# Add compiler flag only if --default-library=shared is used

Tags: meson-build

The meson build system allows to either build shared or static libraries with the option `--default-library`. However I am not able to know if a shared or static library is being built and I need that to pass at least a define. Is there a way to query the library type?

This was my guess:

```
libtype = get_option('default-library')
if libtype = 'shared'
  build_dll = ['-DBUILDING_DLL', '-fvisibility=hidden']
else
  build_dll = ''
endif
```

But apparently I get:

```
Meson encountered an error in file meson.build, line 10, column 0:
Tried to access unknown option "default-library".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else has this issue, the solution is simple:

```
libtype = get_option('default_library')
```

(note the *underscore* instead of the *dash*)

(Credit for the answer goes to jpakkane (the creator of meson), who answered on IRC)